# [ROS2] Example to publish custom message

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an example project for publishing a custom message in ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326818/%5Bros2%5D-example-to-publish-custom-message/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an example message package [pendulum_msgs](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/pendulum_msgs) which is used by [pendulum_control](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/pendulum_control). It [does publish the custom messages](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/f78dcc981cc783aad162e2a8530a7aa23c4fda21/pendulum_control/src/pendulum_demo.cpp#L159-L161).

I found them from this [stub tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Defining-custom-interfaces-(msg-srv)/). That example shows having messages in a dedicated package (which is considered good practice). I don't know of an example where messages are both generated and used in the same package.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-24**:
Thanks for the pointer!